# magento create an account with billing info added

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to have the customer give us their billing address and phone # on the create an account page.

Right now it is 
First Name
Last Name
Email
(Phone Number) add on
(Billing Address) add on
Sign up for Newsletter
Password
Confirm Password

I am trying to figure out what page I would add these fields to. I seem to have these fields once you click create an account and get to the account dashboard. So I would like to just use these fields and move them forward a page to be required from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form fields are already present in registration template (in default theme)

simply add this to local.xml of your theme to enable them

```
<customer_account_create> 
  <reference name="customer_form_register"> 
    <action method="setShowAddressFields">
      <param>true</param>
    </action> 
  </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Comment: I have added this to my theme/default/layout/local.xml file

however I am still not getting address fields on my website/customer/account/create/ page.

Comment: I take it back, it worked, just took longer than expected to clear cache